# Green function elliptic operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, greens-function

I am trying to compute the Green function of 
$$
-\Delta u+u
$$
using Fourier transform:
$(|\xi|^2+1)\hat{u}=1$.
Is there any reference where I can find this calculation?

thank you.

I started with Fubini:
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{e^{i\xi\cdot x}}{1+|\xi|^2}d\xi=$
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}d\xi_{n-1}e^{i(x_2\xi_2+..+\xi_nx_n)}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{i\xi_1\cdot x_1}}{1+\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2+..+\xi_n^2}d\xi_1$

Using contour integration of $\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{izx_1}}{z^2+s^2}dz$

where
$s^2=1+\xi_2^2+..+\xi_n^2$

on half circle (whose radii $R\to\infty$) in the upper half plane. The result is

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{i\xi_1\cdot x_1}}{1+\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2+..+\xi_n^2}d\xi_1=2\pi i \cdot f(is)$ where

$f(z)=\frac{e^{izx_1}}{z+is}$.

To continue forward the next integral ($d\xi_2$) I need to evaluate

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{i\xi_2 x_2}\cdot e^{-sx_1}}{-\sqrt{1+\xi_2^2+..+\xi_n^2}} d\xi_2$

It looks very complicated. maybe there is a better way?

thank you

Comment: The equation is $-\Delta u + u = \delta$. Assuming the "differential equations" normalization of the FT, this becomes $|\omega|^2 \hat{u} + \hat{u} = 1$ in the Fourier domain. Hence $\hat{u}=\frac{1}{1+|\omega|^2}$. It now remains to compute the inverse FT, i.e. $u(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{e^{i \omega \cdot x}}{1+|\omega|^2} d \omega$. Is your question just about this last integration?

Comment: thank you for the answer.  yes

Comment: You should describe how far you got in your own question, then.

Comment: [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280212/how-do-i-derive-the-greens-function-for-nabla2-m2-in-d-dimensions/280213#280213) doesn't follow the track requested, but you can use it to check your answer if you swap in $m=1$.

Comment: "I started with Fubini..." Is there a reason for not going straight for hyperspherical coordinates where: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{e^{i\xi \cdot x}}{1 + |\xi|^2} d\xi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{e^{i|\xi| |x| \cos \theta}}{1 + |\xi|^2} |\xi|^{n-1} d \Omega_{n} d |\xi|,$$ where the integral over $d\Omega_{n}$ is the integral over solid angle in $n$-dimensions?

Comment: Thank you. I will try the spherical coordinates.

Comment: This is worked out in L.C. Evans PDE book in Chapter 4. The fundamental solution is $u(x) = \frac{1}{(4\pi)^{n/2}} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}}{t^{n/2}} \, dt$.